# mmap is wiping my file instead of copying it

Tags: c, mmap

So I'm using mmap to then write to another file. But the weird thing is, when my code hits mmap, what it does is clears the file. So I have a file that's populated with random characters (AB, HAA, JAK, etc...). What it's supposed to do is use mmap as read basically and then write that file to the new file. So that first if (argc == 3) is the normal read and write, the second if (argc ==4) is supposed to use mmap. Does anyone have any idea why on Earth this is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int nbyte = 512;
    char buffer[nbyte];
    unsigned char *f;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int size;
    int totalBuffer;
    struct stat s;
    const char * file_name = argv[1];
    int fd = open (argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    int i = 0;
    char c;

    int fileInput = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    int fileOutPut = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    fstat(fileInput, &s);
    size = s.st_size;
    printf("%d\n", size);
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        printf("size: %d\n", size);
        printf("nbyte: %d\n", nbyte);

        while (size - bytesRead >= nbyte)
        {
            read(fileInput, buffer, nbyte);
            bytesRead += nbyte;
            write(fileOutPut, buffer, nbyte);
        }

        read(fileInput, buffer, size - bytesRead);
        write(fileOutPut, buffer, size - bytesRead);
    }

    else if (argc == 4)
    {
        int i = 0;
        printf("4 arg\n");
        f = (char *) mmap (0, size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fileInput, 0);
        /* This is where it is being wipped */
    }

    close(fileInput);
    close(fileOutPut);

    int who = RUSAGE_SELF;
    struct rusage usage;
    int ret;

    /* Get the status of the file and print some.   Easy to do what "ls" does with fstat system call...  */
    int status = fstat (fd, & s);
    printf("File Size: %d bytes\n",s.st_size);
    printf("Number of Links: %d\n",s.st_nlink);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I wanted to mention that the first read and write works perfectly, it is only when you try to do it through the mmap.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the output file when `argc == 4`. Are you expecting something to happen?

Comment: No, I'm looking at the file itself. The file (words) before going in has a size of ~3,0000. After, the size is 0. I realized something weird was going on when I tried to just print out the first character of f and it seg faulted.

Comment: Can you check `f` against `MAP_FAILED`, and then print `errno` if it failed?  That should give you some clue for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean it's clearing your *destination* file, then yes, that's exactly what your code will do.

It opens the destination with truncation and then, in your `argc==4` section, you map the input file but do absolutely nothing to transfer the data to the output file.

You'll need a `while` loop of some description, similar to the one in the `argc==3` case, but which writes the bytes in *mapped memory* to the `fileOutput` descriptor.

Comment: No, it's clearing the source file. ./mycp words words2 <- it clears words. When I tried to just print out f[0] for example, it seg faulted.

Comment: @Jen, there's a lot of non checking of return values in your code. What is the value of `f` after `mmap`. Make sure it's not MAP_FAILED.

Comment: It is failed, that's the problem. I'm not sure why it is though.

Comment: @Jen, possibly because you're supplying a zero size, assuming the file is already truncated.